# Python ORM SQLAlchemy and Django usage

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I am developing a Flex based dashboard and I am considering SQLAlchemy or Django to interact with the database.

I am new to both these frameworks. I know that Django can create the database with *syncdb* command and SQLAlchemy can do the same with *metadata.create_all(engine)* statement. How do I use these frameworks with an existing database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Django take a look at [Integrating Django with a legacy database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs). I have no experience with SQLAlchemy, though I would assume they have something similar.

Comment: Tips for cleaning up the models can be found at http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18/

Answer (score 0):

define a class for mapper function
e.g

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:@localhost/testdb",echo = True)
#testbd is ur database#use password->> "password"@localhost

metadata = MetaData(engine)
session = create_session()

person_table = Table('person', metadata,
                     Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
                     Column('name', String(40)),
                     Column('age', Integer),
                     Column('about', String(100))
                     )

metadata.create_all(engine)

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age,about):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.about = about
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name, self.age, self.about

mapper(Person, person_table)

#for insert do the below
a_person = Person('Name','Age','About')
session.add(a_person)
session.flush()
```

Comment: For anything more please inform. I'll try my best